# Inside Mechanism Of ToString()

Tags: c#, string, tostring

Does anyone know the backend mechanism inside ToString() method.
That it considers everything as object & returns string.

Say I wish to build a method similar to ToString() I will definitely have an object parameter convert action inside method & finally return the resultant via return type.

So how does ToString() method do that without taking a parameter?

Comment: Can you rephrase please? That is quite hard to understand. But: `ToString()` is implemented separately on a per-type bases (for those that need to override it).

Comment: It's part of interface

Comment: I'll try to make what @MarcGravell even more clear. [`Object::ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) is a [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) method that can be [`override`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)n at any point in hierarchy. Default implementation (i.e. if it's not overriden) calls `GetType()` method and then `ToString` method on returned object by `GetType`.

Answer (score 3):

It is just an instance method that returns a string, no magic inside. If the given object's type does not override `ToString` in a custom way, it will return the fully qualified name of the type

MSDN: [`object.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx).

> The default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully
>   qualified name of the type of the Object, as the following example
>   shows.

```
Object obj = new Object();
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); // System.Object
```

But as mentioned you are free to override `ToString` in your classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
User saddam = new User { ID = 1, Name = "Saddam" };
Console.WriteLine(saddam.ToString()); // "Saddam"
```

Don't be angry with me, but i have the feeling that it might be helpful to read some tutorials about OOP.

MSDN: [Object-Oriented Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx)

Comment: My Dear i am really glad for your concern, i know that i can override the ToString()
Perhaps You did not understand or I was unable to clarify my question
the class members that i have defined in my class of which the parent class has no knowledge
so i am not passing any parameter to ToString()
how it knows that i have passed a parameter and it has to identify it and convert it into string.
2ndly why its considering the value as an object because (.) comes after the object to connect the method

Comment: @SaddamRanjhani: sorry, i don't understand you. Maybe you want to edit your question and provide sample code which often helps to understand a question. In general, `ToString` does not have and does not need a parameter since it's an instance method. That means(read my link provided at the end of my answer) that you need an instance of the type. Then you can use this method(or property).  The inheritance hierarchy dictates the last type in your class' family tree which overrides `ToString`. This implementation is taken if you call `myObj.ToString()`.

Comment: class A{
    protected string ToString()
    {   }

    class B : A
    {
    public static void Main()
    {
    int TempIntVar = 645;
    string TempStringVar=TempIntVar.ToString();
    string TempString2 = 555.ToSTring();
    Console.WriteLine(TempString2 +" "+TempStringVar+" "+TempIntVar);
    Console.ReadLine();
    }

    }
    
Assume there is no ToString() available by default
What I want you to implement the ToString() method in class A in a way that whatever code is written in class B becomes valid.

It will be easy for me to understand it
Thanx in advance anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Every object is responsible for implementing its own ToString() method.

There is no single method which evaluates any and every type of object.

Comment: My Dear i am really glad for your concern, i know that i can override the ToString()
Perhaps You did not understand or I was unable to clarify my question
the class members that i have defined in my class of which the parent class has no knowledge
so i am not passing any parameter to ToString()
how it knows that i have passed a parameter and it has to identify it and convert it into string.
2ndly why its considering the value as an object because (.) comes after the object to connect the method